# SQL field contains a string (comma delimited or at start/end)

Tags: sql, sql-like

I have a field `ERR_CODES` on my db that contains some error codes for the current record.

For example, it can contain:

```
Invalid_Template_Code_Filename_WCLS,Color_Template_Of_Different_Domain_WCLS,Section_Not_Found_WCLS
```

Suppose I want to test if it contains `Section_Not_Found_WCLS`, without adding a comma at the start and at the end of the field.

I should test for:

```
WHERE "ERR_CODES" LIKE '%,Section_Not_Found_WCLS,%'  --between other errs
   OR "ERR_CODES" LIKE 'Section_Not_Found_WCLS,%'    --at start of a err sequence
   OR "ERR_CODES" LIKE '%,Section_Not_Found_WCLS'    --at end of a err sequence
   OR "ERR_CODES"   =  'Section_Not_Found_WCLS'      --unique err for this record
```

This is not really beautiful.

Is there a way to compact that, using wildcards?

**EDIT:**

In RegEx this would be `((?<=,)|^)Section_Not_Found_WCLS((?=,)|$)`

Ideally, I want a solution that will work on each of Oracle, MSSQL, PGSQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WHERE "ERR_CODES" LIKE '%Section_Not_Found_WCLS%'
```

**EDIT:**

```
 WHERE ',' + "ERR_CODES" + ',' LIKE '%,Section_Not_Found_WCLS,%'
```

Comment: No, this will return `TRUE` even for `My_Section_Not_Found_WCLS`

Comment: Yes, I thought about the solution proposed in your edit. This would be a good solution. (anyway, I think you missed a % at the end, didn't you?)

Comment: Yes, thanks. Fixed. Based on RDBMS syntax for string concatenation might be different. I am not sure if it will work same on other then SQL Server.

Comment: That's OK indeed. I have a custom Query Builder that builds concatenation based on the current DBMS :)

Comment: @Teejay There is to some degree, but it's not that complex and again differ greatly for each RDBMS. Check T-SQL examples at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx

Comment: Unfortunately, `%`, `_` and `[]`/`[^]` char classes ***seem*** not sufficient to achieve my result.

Answer (score 1):

Another possible thing to consider, is making the database more relational as it is the standard.

Rather than keeping a bunch of strings in a line, make a extra table, to keep things more organized. I have created a image to depict exactly what I mean.

[image: Suggestion]

Comment: Good point, but this is actually a batch generated temporary table and storing err_codes in another table is not worthy.